# How to calculate the infiltration rate?

Tags: geology, hydrology, homework

This is Exercise 4.8.1 in *Introduction to Physical Hydrology* by Martin Hendriks.

The water level above flat terrain during an experiment with double ring infiltrometer is 20 mm. The saturated hydraulic conductivity of soil is 20 mm/h. The wetting front of soil suction is 60 mm. The initial soil moisture content is 20% and the effective porosity is 45%.

Calculate the infiltration rate and cumulative infiltration when wetting front is 20, 40, 80, 160, 320, 640 and 1280 mm below the soil surface. Why does the infiltration rate diminish with time?

Comment: This looks like a homework question

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a homework question that shows no attempt at a solution on the part of the asker. See [the homework question policy](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-earth-science-stack-exchange/317#317) for details of how to ask homework questions, and note that this site does **not** offer a ‘do my homework for me’ service.